# Bash Script to remove leading and trailing spaces for all files in a directory

Tags: bash, macos, automator

I would like to just add it to Automator and let the user choose the directory in which it runs. One Drive will not upload files with space. I managed to remove all spaces but not remove all spaces from the beginning and the end.

My code:

```
for f in "$1"/*; do
  dir=$(dirname "$f")
  file=$(basename "$f")
  mv "$f" "${dir}/${file//[^0-9A-Za-z.]}"
done
```

Comment: It is unclear, but I presume you are talking about the file *name* and not the file *contents*. You can simply use a `for` or `while` loop, or `find` with `-maxdepth 1` (unless you want a recursive find), and since you are using bash, you can use parameter expansion to remove both the leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob                        # Enable extended globbing syntax
for path in "$1"/*; do
  file=${path##*/}                      # Trim directory name
  file=${file##+([[:space:]])}          # Trim leading spaces
  file=${file%%+([[:space:]])}          # Trim trailing spaces
  if [[ $file != "${path##*/}" ]]; then # Skip files that aren't changed
    mv -- "$path" "$1/${file}"
  fi
done
```

Notes:

- A shell needs to be started with `bash`, not `sh`, to ensure that extensions (such as extglobbing and `[[ ]]`) are available.
- There's no need to call `dirname`, since we always know the directory name: It's in `$1`.
- `extglob` syntax  extends regular glob expressions to have power comparable to regexes. `+([[:space:]])` is extglob for "one or more spaces", whereas the `${var%%pattern}` and `${var##pattern}` remove as many characters matching `pattern` as possible from the back or front, respectively, of a variable's value.
- There's no point to running a `mv` when the filename didn't need to change, so we can optimize a bit by checking first.

Comment: How do I call it in Automator so my user can choose the dir to run it in ? I ask for a Finder Item. then set that as a Var, the Run a shell script .

Comment: Couldn't tell you -- my area of expertise is bash, not Automator. However, if you can successfully start your original script from Automator, I'd expect the same mechanism to work for the new one.

Comment: This is where the *extended pattern matching* options with `extglob` shine, Without it you end up with `file="${file#"${file%%[![:space:]]*}"}"` and `file="${file%"${file##*[![:space:]]}"}"` to accomplish the same thing (much messier...)

Comment: It works great in Automator if you pass the Variable in as an argument vs. stdin (which I was).  it only seems to remove the leading space (and if there is only one space not multiple) does not remove the trailing (one or more). "extglob" should be removing multiple spaces correct or should I be using the "${var%%pattern}" -

Comment: @JacquelineRay, `+([[:space:]])` is an extglob that can match multiple spaces; using `%%` causes this code to look for more than one. See https://ideone.com/zVMYP5 for an example of this code working with more than one space in both leading and trailing positions.